# Node script use folder name as parameter

Tags: node.js

I want to execute a command for each directory in my packages directory. In the command I want to use part of the directory name.

```
packages 
  folder-one
  folder-two
  folder-three
```

So for each folder execute `command 'one'` etc

Does anyone have some pointers for this?

Comment: Just hard code the constant part. Like ``folder-${name}``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fs.readdir` to list directory contents and `child_process.exec` to run the command:

```js
const { readdir } = require('fs/promises');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
readdir(__dirname + '/packages').then(packages => {
    for (let packageName of packages) {
        packageName = packageName.replace(/^folder-/, ''); // remove the 'folder-' part
        exec(`your_command_here '${__dirname}/packages/${packageName}'`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            // if needed you can read the process' stdout and stderr
        });
    }
});
```